# Best practices for permissions in major directories in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, chmod

I want to know the best permission settings for all the default directories (by which I mean the ones in `/` that are already there when you first install) and then any other specifics that are important.

What I want to do is have a bash script set all the permissions on the computer it is run on, because I do a lot of stuff that involves changing permissions on a bunch of different computers so it would be great to not have to do each thing individually.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one fits all when it comes to permissions. The answer is going to depend on what is the purpose of the computer.

For instance, a personal computer for your own use has nothing to do with a web server, or with a multiuser computer that has, for example, 100 different users in the /home directory.

For every situation you should define a permissions policy that adjusts to your needs.

Having said that, since you mentioned you are a bit new, you might want to look at, setuid, setgid and sticky bits. They are very handy when it comes to implementing certain permissions and control policies.

Cheers

Comment: What about in general though. I mean some things you would not want to be open to anyone such as a user's home directory.